# Windows Service in C# doesn't run as SYSTEM for all users

Tags: c#, windows-services, user-permissions

I have developped a service that prevents downloading external plugins for a hardware device. It preloads them by starting a program in the background and is fully transparant for the users.

My idea was to run it as a service, since then I would be able to run it as a SYSTEM-user.

My program is working, but only for my administrator accounts (in active directory). When I launch the service, it starts the program under SYSTEM-user:

[image]

When I log in as a standard user, the service lets the program also launch but not under SYSTEM, so it fails (user needs to manually download the plugins):

[image]

What can I do to run the service as SYSTEM for standard users?

I have tried changing the properties of the service (log on as 'admin credentials') but nothing seemed to work

Comment: Are you not suspicious that the user name doesn't appear for any of the other processes (csrss.exe, etc.) when run in this mode...?

Comment: Uhh it's a standard user in a active directory environment. Are you pointing me out to a possible mistake that I've done or an obvious problem that I need to notice? I have tried everything actually

Comment: I don't understand the phrase, "the service lets the program also launch..."  What is the program?  What is the program's parent process?

Comment: The process (program) generates a token. What my plan is, is to install the program as an admin on a terminal server ( windows server 2012) and launch the program on every login. This would mean that users do not need to run the program everytime while logging in and have an annoying cmd window on their screen.

Comment: I'm suggesting that maybe it _is_ running correctly, but that you're unable to see the username column because of something else... I'm not saying this is your problem; I'm saying I'd rule that out first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Roger. I have just noticed my problem. I installed the program (using the installer) with Administrator privileges and I thought all of the users of the domain would have it also installed. This is not the case however so I'm guessing I need to make sure that the program also get's installed in the user?